# how to update and refresh the viewpager textview dynamically in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment

I have five fragments in view pager and every fragments has a single star rating(five images) question and text view on it.The text view needs to display the number of questions answered. if the user select the answer from the fragment, then the text view need to be incremented by 1 and moves to the next fragment.

While i am trying to implement that,The fragment transition occurs perfectly but the answer count does not updated properly in the text view.

```
starhighImage.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (action)
        {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        starlowImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.starsosad);
        starsadImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.starsad);
        starnormalImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.starnormal);
        starhappyImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.stargood);
        starhighImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.starsogood);
        updateProgress();
        moveFragment.onMoveFragmentDialog();
        return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});


public void updateProgress()
    {
        int questionCount,answerCount;
        questionCount=dbo.getQuestioncount(dbo);
        answerCount=dbo.GetCountTempAns(dbo);

        txt_starProgress.setText(Integer.toString(answerCount)+"/"+Integer.toString(questionCount));
        txt_starProgress.requestLayout();
        txt_starProgress.invalidate();
    }
```

Comment: try doing txt_starProgress.setText(String.valueOf(answerCount)+"/"+String.valueOf(questionCount));

Comment: i have tried already,It's not working,.

Comment: First two fragments does not update the text view but the third fragment displayed the text view content properly.

Answer (score 0):

I did not get your question fully, what I understood I am trying to answer.
just take any array or arraylist when user answers just add 1 number to array or arraylist then display answercount as the size of list.

if you are making any changes to any array or array list you passed to adapter.
then try calling notfiydatasetchanged.

I know this is not an optimised solution. hope it helps. please post whole code for better answers. thank you